# Why onscroll function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am making div element that should fade in/out on scroll. I tried simply alerting on scroll(without fading) with onscroll, scroll, DOMMouseScroll, mousewheel, also with jquery, but it doesn't work with any of these. Only works with onmousewheel in Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/643v7rod/

```
var el = document.getElementById('el');

var opacity = 1;
el.onmousewheel = function(e){
    if(e.deltaY > 0){
        opacity -= 0.25;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
    }else{
        opacity += 0.25;
        el.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That mouse event has been deprecated, see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseWheelEvent)

Try this one instead, and make sure your div's height is enough so that you can scroll :)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el');
var opacity = 1;
//if you want to be able to revert the effect, you will
//have to store the current window position 
//in a variable and update it each time;
var position = window.scrollY;
//declaring the function
function effect(){
 if(window.scrollY > position){
  opacity -= 0.01;
  el.style.opacity = opacity;
        //now update the positoin
        position = window.scrollY;
 }else{
  opacity += 0.01;
  el.style.opacity = opacity;
        //do it again
        position = window.scrollY;
 }
};
//adding the event listener
window.addEventListener("scroll", effect);
```

```css
#el {
 width: 300px;
 height: 1200px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

I have changed the opacity rate so that you get a clear visual of the effect.